# Dspace Advance search XMLUI Customizaiton

Tags: dspace

I want to change filter please help how can i do this.. I want meeting type document title into my filter search please help me..

Thanks in advance

[image: <code>Filter</code>]

[image: I want this types in filter]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a new facet in the discovery XML file.

#### Define facet

```
<bean id="searchFilterType" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.HierarchicalSidebarFacetConfiguration">
    <property name="indexFieldName" value="type"/>
    <property name="metadataFields">
        <list>
            <value>dc.type.*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="facetLimit" value="10"/>
    <property name="sortOrderSidebar" value="COUNT"/>
    <property name="sortOrderFilterPage" value="COUNT"/>
    <property name="splitter" value="::"/>
</bean>
```

Once you have added your new facet, you can add to the filter list and optionally to the sidebar facets.

#### Search Filters

```
   <property name="searchFilters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="searchFilterTitle" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />

            <!-- Add new facet -->
            <ref bean="searchFilterType" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterContentInOriginalBundle"/>
        </list>
```

#### Sidebar facet (if desired)

```
    <property name="sidebarFacets">
        <list>
            <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />

            <!-- Add new facet -->
            <ref bean="searchFilterType" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
            <ref bean="searchFilterContentInOriginalBundle"/>
        </list>
```

In XMLUI, you must provide a translation for your new facet headers in your i18n/messages.xml file.

```
<!-- MAKING DSPACE YOUR OWN WEBNINAR ADDITIONS -->
<message key="xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.AdvancedSearch.type_type">Type</message>
<message key="xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.SimpleSearch.filter.type">Type</message>
<message key="xmlui.Discovery.AbstractSearch.type_type">Type</message>
```

Additionally, the following presentation describes how to add a type facet to a DSpace collection.

https://gitpitch.com/DSpace-Labs/DSpace-rel-demo/webinar?grs=github#/10

Comment: if you can help me code on my requirement It would be very help full for me

Comment: This answer is the best help that I am able to offer.

Comment: is this possible to change the value of  "dc.title"?